# Can’t Edit CS File in Console Project in VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I recently had to move from VS 2015 Professional to VS 2017 Community Edition.I have a console application that was created with 2015 Pro but can no longer be edited in 2017 Community. The project opens and builds without error. However, as soon as I click inside the code editor for any .cs file it locks up and shuts down. I can’t even add a break point to the file without it shutting down. Apparently the break point is added but it still shuts down when interacting with the code editor.

A couple of points: (1) I’m running on a virtual windows on a MacBook Pro via Parallels; (2) My files are located on Dropbox.

Comment: Can you create a new project and add the cs files to it?

Comment: I’m not sure. I just ran the application and am now able to edit files. Don’t understand why it prevented editing before hand. I did notice then when I opened the project up, the Output window said could not map...